# How do I bring back the orbit gizmo in the top right of the viewport?

Tags: 3d-view, workflow, gizmo

I've been looking this up for a while now, I'm new to blender. I've been working on a project for a while now in 2.8 and I'm pretty sure I hit some shortcut but in that specific save file in the layout workspace the orbit gizmo you use to easily swap orthographic perspectives disappeared, it seems like some random shortcut that I pressed when trying to recall a different one. ctrl-space is not working and load factory setting loses all my work the modeling workspace is unaffected so I could probably change that around to get a similar workspace without the problem but it would be better to know what's causing the problem so I don't do it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Navigate gizmo* can be enabled in the overlay menu.
And all gizmos can be (accidentally) disabled through <kbd>Ctrl + `</kbd>

[image]